# Meaning of $\overline{F}$ for a field $F$

Tags: field-theory

I am reading a text on group theory, and I keep seeing a field $F$ with a bar over it. It looks something like this:

$$\bar{F_p}$$

What is its meaning?

Comment: $\overline{F}$ typically denotes the algebraic closure of a given field $F$.

Comment: Using simple LaTeX  would avoid having to open another file for reading a question. It is  " dollar bar F dollar" here.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the [algebraic closure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlgebraicClosure.html) of the field.